# SSL: Display unscure items through php proxy

Tags: php, ssl, proxy, https

My site is protected with SSL (https) I need to embed some images that are on an unsecured site (http).

How can I avoid the security errors recieved when trying to show content that was not delivered through https.

Example: http://0.chart.apis.google.com/chart?chtt=Answered+Calls&cht=bhs&chs=780x150&chbh=35,0,15&chg=8.33,0,5,5&chd=t:0,2&chco=4D89F9|C6D9FD&chf=bg,s,f8f8f8&chxt=x,y&chxl=1:|Answered|Unanswered&chds=0,2&chxr=0,0,2

Is there anyway I can pass this through a proxy to avoid errors???

Answer (score 0):

Put this into a file called "chart.php" and use it as the image's `src`:

```
<?php
echo readfile("http://0.chart.apis.google.com/chart?chtt=Answered+Calls&cht=bhs&chs=780x150&chbh=35,0,15&chg=8.33,0,5,5&chd=t:0,2&chco=4D89F9|C6D9FD&chf=bg,s,f8f8f8&chxt=x,y&chxl=1:|Answered|Unanswered&chds=0,2&chxr=0,0,2");
?>
```

Comment: In addition, you could adjust the file to accept the same query string as you send to the chart API; then, you could use the file for more than one chart.

Comment: I do this but it doesn't display correctly:

   <img src="<?php
echo readfile("http://0.chart.apis.google.com/chart?chtt=Answered+Calls&cht=bhs&chs=780x150&chbh=35,0,15&chg=8.33,0,5,5&chd=t:0,2&chco=4D89F9|C6D9FD&chf=bg,s,f8f8f8&chxt=x,y&chxl=1:|Answered|Unanswered&chds=0,2&chxr=0,0,2");
?>
" />

Comment: Right, because you're dumping the bytes of the image into the src attribute. You need to do this: `src="chart.php"`, where chart.php is the name of the file whose contents are what I gave you above.

Comment: cool that works, I will have to pass the variables to it in the URL i guess